# invalid on specified as date, must be a column (if DataFrame) or None

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The following line gives me error:
 invalid on specified as date, must be a column (if DataFrame) or None

How to resolve it?

```
test_data=pd.DataFrame({'date':['20190606','20190610','20190708','20190805','20190909','20190930'],'number':[3,5,4,1,0,0],\
                       'avg_last_2m':[None,3,4,4,1,0.5]})
test_data['date']=pd.to_datetime(test_data['date'])
print(test_data.rolling('90d', on='date')['number'].agg({'sum','count'}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, @Andy's answer was correct, it's likely a bug. Although passing a dictionary to `agg` is deprecated.

You can also fix it by:

```
test_data.set_index('date').rolling('90d')['number'].agg({'sum','count'})
```

output:

```
            count   sum
date                   
2019-06-06    1.0   3.0
2019-06-10    2.0   8.0
2019-07-08    3.0  12.0
2019-08-05    4.0  13.0
2019-09-09    3.0   5.0
2019-09-30    4.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in your `agg`. Try this:

```
test_data.rolling('90d', on='date')['number'].agg({'sum':sum,'count':'count'})
```

Output:

```
    sum     count
0   3.0     1.0
1   8.0     2.0
2   12.0    3.0
3   13.0    4.0
4   5.0     3.0
5   5.0     4.0
```